# Windows 10 golang setup. Error, Not in an environment

Tags: go

I am running into issues setting up go for the first time on a Windows 10 machine.

I followed the instructions from the install. https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.10.windows-386.msi

When I CD to my project `E:\goProjects\goWebApp\src` and run `go build`, I receive the following error.

```
C:\windows\system32>go version
Not in an environment
C:\Users\MyUser~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go_there.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

My system variables are as follows:

- `GOPATH=E:\goProjects\goWebApp`
- `GOROOT=C:\Go`
- `PATH=C:\Go\bin`

If I run go version from `C:\Go\bin` everything works fine. Running go command from anywhere outside of this directory does not work. I have also tried restarting my cmd prompt and restarting my computer. Still no luck. Has anyone else ran into this issue? Or know what I might have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your project should not be in the top level of `GOPATH/src`. Did you _add_ `GOROOT/bin` to your PATH, or did you replace everything else in your path? You probably want `GOPATH/bin` in your `PATH` too. What is `go_there.bat`?

Comment: I am not sure what `go_there.bat` is. I think go creates that on the fly. When I search for it in temp it is not there. I did not add GOROOT/bin to my path. But the installer added it like this `C:\Go\bin`. Should it be like this? `%GOROOT%\bin` ?

Comment: No, since `GOROOT` doesn't need to be set `C:\Go\bin` is fine, I was asking if that's the _only_ thing in your path. Run `go build -x` to see what exactly is being executed and failing (and move your project into a subdir of `src`)

Comment: I removed GOROOT now. I only have `PATH=C:\Go\bin` and `GOPATH=E:\goProjects\goWebApp` I followed these instructions. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH If I run the `go` command from command prompt `C:\windows\system32>go` I get that same error.

Comment: Why are you running go from `C:\windows\system32>`? At least start in your project directory, then provide the full command you're running, and output you're getting.

Comment: I assumed it was similar to a Java install or Node. Where it would be globally available after installing. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something? Should I not be able to run `go version` from anywhere?

Comment: yes, you should be able to run `go version` from anywhere, but that has nothing to do with the `go build` error. Have you restarted your cmd shell to make sure you have the new PATH configured?

Comment: Yes I have restarted it several times. I attached a screenshot (just now). This isn't a build error. I get the same error when running `go version` It is a configuration issue. This is the first time I have ever attempted to use go. I am just trying to setup a working environment at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know windows very well, but this doesn't look like anything to do with the Go toolchain itself, and there's something else in your path being executed by that command.

Comment: @JimB, I figured out what was going on. Thanks for your help though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had two *go* locations in my *PATH* (*sort of*). When I ran the command `where go` from command prompt two paths were returned.

Something like this..

```
C:\tools\devTools\bin
C:\Go\bin\go.exe
```

There apparently was a bat file in `devTools\bin` called ***go.bat***. This was unrelated to golang itself, just coincidental naming unfortunately.This was executing instead of the go binary, which in return was throwing the random error with the `Not in an environment` message.

*To fix the issue I just removed the devTools path from my PATH variable for now.*